# Where to find scientific, unbiased research on a supplement

Tags: supplement, scientific-method

My middle-aged father is insistent on knowing about Nutriversus (created by Mannatech). He believes this can help sharpen the brain.

Before buying, taking any supplement, I am researching information about Nutriversus. Unfortunately, an internet search gives biased info about how great this supplement is.

I went to WebMD, Drugs.com, and cannot find information about Nutriversus anywhere.

Please tell me, where else can I search for scientific, unbiased research on this supplement.

Comment: Have you tried to go for single ingredients? Related to this issue [How do I evaluate health benefits and health advertisements of products?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/13712/how-do-i-evaluate-health-benefits-and-health-advertisements-of-products)