# can smoking ashwagandha have the same benefit as the power/pill form?

Tags: diabetes, smoking, stress, anxiety-disorders, traditional-medicine

I been reading a lot of positive benefits from ashwagandha lately such as

- Keeping blood sugar balanced
- Boosting testosterone levels
- Reducing level of stress and anxiety
- Boost brain function
- Having anti cancer properties

and many others and as person who's been suffering from general anxiety disorder for over a decade now while basically having both diabetes and cancer encrypted in my dna I dont think I could of asked for anything better. 
Would smoking  ashwagandha bring the same health benefits as taking it in pill or powdered form would? Which form (route of administration) delivers the most health benefits?

Comment: Smoking is never really healthy. Especially the anti cancer property is bonkers. a) Cancer is a random mutation of genes, and while that process isn’t yet fully comprehended I can assure you ingested molecules have nothing to do with it unless they promote building of free radicals and other cancerous molecules. b) Smoking of any kind will make you inhale carbonmonoxide, which isn’t great for your lungs. So, the answer would be no, because ashwagandha doesn’t have these properties at all. // It would be great if you could link to the resources that claim this, maybe their line of reasoning is

Comment: [cont‘d] a little off but there’s still truth to some claims. We can only verify that if you show us the source though...

Comment: Also, take a look at this guide on [how to evaluate health effects of products](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/13712/8212)

Comment: Smoking something to prevent cancer.... Now there's a concept.