# Does hair gel damage your hair?

Tags: side-effects, hair

I've been using hair gel for years now ( Taft gel from Schwarzkopf ), and after a day of using said gel when I scratch my hair there is a small amount of hair i take of glued up togheter. I‘m too young to go bold naturally.  So can a certain type of gel couse a personal hair loss.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. I‘ve edited your question a bit. For the future, you might want to consider using a spell checker. Sometimes minor typos escape anyone :). // Do you have long hair or short hair? // It is highly unlikely that Shampoo causes these troubles of yours, it rather has something to do with your morning routine. I would redirect you to LifeHacks though because we on Health.SE mostly focus on health aspects in the sense of medicine, and because you state yourself how this is not due to hairloss, I fail to see how this is related to health.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not asking about a health effect of a product per se, but rather seeking for fashion advice regarding hair.

Comment: I'm not certain I necessarily agree - I interpret the question as it asking whether a certain type of shampoo (or chemical ingredient) could cause premature hair loss. Is this what you're asking, @Spellcaster ?

Comment: @Taylor Yes, that is what i'm asking

Comment: @Spellcaster - In that case, would you mind rephrasing your question? :)

Comment: Asking for the cause of hair loss is asking for personal medical advice. Voting to close.

Comment: Adding on @CareyGregory 's comment: We do have a guideline on how to research such questions and require at least a certain bit of research: https://health.stackexchange.com/q/13712/8212

Comment: @LangLangC It is about gel not shampoo. Someone edited it.

Comment: @Spellcaster So you've put gel inside your hair, and now you're surprised that it glues hair together? Isn't that like the single purpose of gel?

Comment: @Narusan-sedated I said the hair drops from my head, also the hair that drops is sticky and glued up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main things to consider here:

1. What kind of hairloss is there?
2. What is in the product that is applied to the hair?

**concerning 1:**  All humans loose their hair, constantly. That is part of the life cycle of hair und usually goes quite unnoticed when the hair is short and is progressively more obvious when the hair was allowed to grow longer.

> [The average adult head has about 100,000 to 150,000 hairs and loses up to 100 of them a day; finding a few stray hairs on your hairbrush is not necessarily cause for alarm. 
>  At any one time, about 90% of the hair on a person's scalp is growing. Each follicle has its own life cycle that can be influenced by age, disease, and a wide variety of other factors. This life cycle is divided into three phases: 1. Anagen -- active hair growth that lasts between two to six years 2. Catagen -- transitional hair growth that lasts two to three weeks
>   3. Telogen -- resting phase that lasts about two to three months; **at the end of the resting phase the hair is shed** and a new hair replaces it and the growing cycle starts again.](https://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/hair-loss/understanding-hair-loss-basics#1)

Especially in males going [bald with age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_hair_loss) is very common.

If it is this kind of genetic fate *or* because of underlying medical conditions (toxins, too much supplements…) asking questions on the web is no the best course of action. For that a medical examination is needed and prescriptions for [finasterid or hair transplants](https://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/hair-loss/men-hair-loss-17/slideshow-men-hair-loss-treatment) are equally unsuitable for 'the cloud'. Since hairloss *might* be just a cosmetic issue of aesthetics or an indication for serious issues a visit to a medical practitioner is strongly advised.

**concerning 2.:**  [Checking for the ingredients of a specially preferred product mentioned in the qustion reveals that among other substances it contains some that are found to be of varying concern:](https://www.codecheck.info/kosmetik_koerperpflege/haarstyling/gel/ean_4015000935722/id_1823963/Schwarzkopf_3_Wetter_Taft_Power_Styling_Gel_Mega_Stark.pro)

- PEG-40, PEG-70: tensides, weakens the barrier function of skin
- Triethanolamine: immune system disruptor, potential allergen, irritant, nitrosamine producer
- Acrylates / Steareth-20 Methacrylate Copolymer: weakens barrier function of skin
- Disodium Edta:  weakens cell membranes
- Polyester-5: the glue in the gel
- Phenoxyethanol: preservative, negative influence on immune system and nervous system, potential allergen
- Propylene Glycol: negative influence on immune system, potential allergen, suspected of being toxic or harmful to health
- Citral: potent allergen

That means it is not an unrealistic assumption that indeed the product just causes trouble. It is a conglomerate of questionable ingredients. But that is far from certain! All of these substances are allowed in cosmetics after all. None of them is listed as directly causes premature hair loss.

One explanation to consider is the perceptual issue of an aging man in panic finding these hairs: As stated earlier, hairs are constantly falling out. If some of them were glued together with gel before falling out that might just mean they did not increase in number; but that they only became much more noticeable that way.

Using anything on hair is typically not necessary. If something is supicious: stop using it and watch if conditions improve.

Comment: This is an answer way better than the question deserves